# Canon T7i- won’t power on

Tags: canon, troubleshooting

My 3 year old Canon T7i suddenly decided to stop turning on.  I’ve tried everything including

- powering the battery fully
- replacing the battery twice
- changing the lense
- switching the microswitches on the battery and SD card doors
- replaced the SD card
- connecting the camera to my laptop
- leaving the fully charged battery out overnight
- opened the camera body to check for lose connections

Still won’t power on.  Any other tips?

I searched online and found the t6i has a button cell battery on the main board.. but i didn’t see one on mine. Perhaps it’s on the underside of the board.

Anyone have internal schematics of the T7i body?

I contacted a local repair shop and he told me to send it to canon... I don’t want to pay $400 to repair it when I could buy a t8i body for $750....

Comment: When you say, “replacing the battery twice”, do you mean you have used/tried two different _replacement_ batteries?

Comment: Remove everything from the camera body (e.g. if you use a battery grip, remove it.)  The body can power on with *only* a battery inserted and nothing else (it is not necessary to have a lens attached nor a memory card inserted ... you'll get a 'no card' message, but it can still power on.)  Memory card door and battery door must be fully closed (to engage the micro-switches).  Make sure they aren't damaged.

Any chance you were sold a dud battery?  I have purchased batteries that were completely defunct (Amazon Marketplace seller).  I'm now careful to buy only from a reputable source.

Comment: Depending on in what part of the world you are located, sometimes independent repair shops can be substantially cheaper than "factory service" for diagnosing issues to determine exactly what needs to be replaced. I highly doubt even Canon factory service is available on the Dark Side of the Moon.

Answer (score 1):

The "button cell" is on the underside of the board near the communication ports on the left side of the camera, as viewed by the photographer when looking at the back of the camera. It can be seen in this picture of a T7i/800D main board, viewed as it would be seen from past the lens in front of the camera.

[image]

Please be aware that some of these are soldered in on some Canon models, even though they appear at first glance to be inserted into a holder.

But a dead time/date battery should not prevent the camera from powering up when a properly charged LP-E17 battery is inserted in the camera. It would only prevent the camera from retaining time/date/settings when the LP-E17 is removed.

Your issue is likely elsewhere.